# Search same words but one word start with caps other word start with small

Tags: c#, search

Here I search Manufacturer

My problem is Manufacturer is Tatavista  in data base Tatavista and tatvista

if I search with tatavista I get both results

I need only if search with tatavista I need to get tatavista only

This is my code:

```
viewModel = CarDb.cars.Where(g => g.Manufacturer == Manufacturer || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Manufacturer.Trim().tolower().toupper()))
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the type of `CarDb`? What ORM are you using?

Comment: CarDB is my database name cars is table name

Comment: But are you using LINQ to SQL, Entity Framerowk...?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
viewModel = CarDb.cars.Where(g => string.Equals(g.Manufacturer, Manufacturer, System.StringComparison.Ordinal) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Manufacturer.Trim()));
```

This will compare strings without ignoring case and sort order. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx).

Comment: i got a exception like .....        Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'

Comment: @Hareesh. Please can you post the full code of the function and stack trace. If you look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx, the parameters are correct.